# React Native Code Push - Is it Possible to update native file changes in remote update ie: Code Push

Tags: java, android, react-native, code-push

I want to remote update for Native file changes. Ie: I'll made some changes in Java or XML file. I'm using react-native-code-push. With this is it possible to update?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. If you change the native files, you have to rebuild your app and distribute a new version

The way codepush works is deeply related to react-native's workings

A react native app is basically a runtime for your Javascript code. It's an app that interprets your JS bundle. The bundle is usually shipped with the runtime. The way codepush works is, instead of trying to run a local bundle, your app now tries to download the new JS bundle from a codepush server.

But keep in mind that it only downloads a fresh JS bundle. The native files are already compiled. If you change your native files, you need to recompile them, and codepush doesn't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to native file changes, such as modifications to Java or XML files, react-native-code-push primarily focuses on updating JavaScript code and assets. If your changes involve native code (Java or XML), you may still need to go through the regular app update process, as those changes typically require a new version of the app to be built and distributed through the app store.